# Why does on_member_join() is not working in my discord.py bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I try to run this code below, but on_member_join is not working for me.

```py
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        guild = member.guild
        if guild.system_channel is not None:
            to_send = f'Welcome {member.mention} to {guild.name}!'
            await guild.system_channel.send(to_send)
            # self.logger.info(f'{member.mention} 加入了伺服器')
```

full code: https://github.com/Cutespirit-Team/CutespiritDiscordBot/blob/main/src/ctbot/ctbot.py#L66-L71

run `python -m src/ctbot/`

I have already turned this on.
[image: server msg intent]

when a user enter my server, it will show the default message.
how can i fix it? thx

Comment: So what kind of problem are you getting?

Comment: there is no errors displayed. i tried to print('test') in every lines, but i "test" didn't show in the terminal

Comment: Since you have `self`, is this in a cog? If so, is it added as a listener?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure to subscribe to members intent.

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        intents = discord.Intents.default()
        intents.members = True
        super().__init__(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Is it right? super().__init__(command_prefix=config.get_general_prefix())

Answer (score -1):

I used this but Im new to this stuff so idk its better or worse just know it works for me:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    embed=discord.Embed(title='Welcome!', description=f"{member.mention} Just Joined")
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: The on_member_join function doesn't seems to run